# Cannot cast BasicDBObject to [B

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, mongo-java

I have the following `gridfs` in a mongodb database:

```
db.outputFs.files.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"), "chunkSize" : 261120, "length" : 232, "md5" : "42290309186cc5420acff293b92ae21d", "filename" : "/tmp/outputFs-01.tmp", "contentType" : null, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-04-13T13:50:48.259Z"), "aliases" : null, "metadata" : { "estado" : "FICHERO_PDTE_ENVIO", "dataDate" : "20141122", "inputOutputFs" : "output", "gridFileCompression" : "bzip2", "fileType" : "OUTPUT-TEST1", "filePath" : "/tmp/outputFs-01.tmp", "sourceParticipant" : "0100", "destinationParticipant" : "REE", "exportFileName" : "F1_0100_20141122_20150219.0", "processed" : "false", "fileMD5" : "4276e61a4b63d3d1d1b77e27e792bd13", "version" : 0 } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000002"), "chunkSize" : 261120, "length" : 232, "md5" : "42290309186cc5420acff293b92ae21d", "filename" : "/tmp/outputFs-02.tmp", "contentType" : null, "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-04-13T13:50:48.259Z"), "aliases" : null, "metadata" : { "estado" : "FICHERO_ENVIADO_OK", "fechaEnvio" : ISODate("2015-04-13T13:50:48.259Z"), "dataDate" : "20141123", "inputOutputFs" : "output", "gridFileCompression" : "bzip2", "fileType" : "OUTPUT-TEST2", "filePath" : "/tmp/outputFs-02.tmp", "sourceParticipant" : "0100", "destinationParticipant" : "REE", "exportFileName" : "F1_0100_20141123_20150220.0", "processed" : "false", "fileMD5" : "4276e61a4b63d3d1d1b77e27e792bd13", "version" : 0 } }



db.outputFs.chunks.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"), "files_id" :  ObjectId("000000000000000000000001"), "n" : 0, "data" : { "$type" : 0, "$binary" : "QlpoOTFBWSZTWZSBQ/YABX5cAAAYQAH/+CAAMAFWA0NqptIb9UgAZ6qowAAFKSaJpGhk8ssmVlk7AAAALZtZZOf0vr859OqflcIs461Dm1skcSOpGpHMuu5HcsJG0j5I9PiR4kaRvvjWskfsVMkZVLxI3uRy/pGTqRj7VmMyTOBfUtb561rwkf0j09+Zbkd+cs1I77861xI7pypvfOt1v5DmR1I51nW7XGdaluRnGZjMzJMzOZGpHnrfGM56+/fnGPVVVVVqqpVVWxCSxCTSAEMkZI3IyqXuqXyRuR/i7kinChISkCh+wA==" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000002"), "files_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000002"), "n" : 0, "data" : { "$type" : 0, "$binary" : "QlpoOTFBWSZTWZSBQ/YABX5cAAAYQAH/+CAAMAFWA0NqptIb9UgAZ6qowAAFKSaJpGhk8ssmVlk7AAAALZtZZOf0vr859OqflcIs461Dm1skcSOpGpHMuu5HcsJG0j5I9PiR4kaRvvjWskfsVMkZVLxI3uRy/pGTqRj7VmMyTOBfUtb561rwkf0j09+Zbkd+cs1I77861xI7pypvfOt1v5DmR1I51nW7XGdaluRnGZjMzJMzOZGpHnrfGM56+/fnGPVVVVVqqpVVWxCSxCTSAEMkZI3IyqXuqXyRuR/i7kinChISkCh+wA==" } }
```

When I try to retrieve it with `Spring Data` or even MongoChef (both Java clients) as a file, I receive the following error:

```
com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to [B
```

The collections were manually imported as they are, not using `MongoChef` or `mongofiles` and I have no idea where this error can come from.

Comment: Can you retrieve them with the `mongofiles` command line?

Comment: `mongofiles list` shows nothing

Comment: As you added java tag so you may be using mongo java driver. Did you try fetching directly using java driver?

Comment: something like :  `GridFSDBFile outputFile = gfs.findOne("/tmp/outputFs-01.tmp");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridFS specification expects a `Binary` field called `data` in the `chunks` collection. However, your `outputFs.chunks` does not meet this criteria.

The `data` field here is not a `Binary` BSON data type but a regular document that happens to have two fields called `$type` and `$data`.

`mongoimport` will create a Binary field only for JSON entries in the following format. Please note that the order of the fields matters for `mongoimport`.

```
{
   "$binary" : ... 
   "$type" : ...
}
```

Your example has the `$type` and `$binary` fields swapped.

Update your JSON file and import your `outputFs.chunks` again. `mongoimport` will create valid Binary fields and you'll be able to work with GridFS using your other MongoDB tools.